# How can I send a code snippet of javascript using Tornado's self.write method?

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, tornado, web-frameworks

I was trying to send a small piece of javascript to the browser, using Tornado's `self.write` method:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    [...]    #deal with arguments, db operation, and so on #async.

    #if _auth_flag is True, then send the alert
    if _auth_flag:
        self.write("<script>alert('Login Successfully');</script>")
        self.redirect("/")

    [...]    #other code
```

when I run the web app, however, no alert was executed.

**MY QUESTIONG IS:**

- Why this code does not work correctly?
- If the code above is not appropriate, how can I send the same alert to browser in other ways?

Answer (score 0):

If you send a redirect, the rest of the response is ignored. You'll have to either only send a redirect and ensure that whatever JS you want appears on the following page, or only send the javascript and have the javascript assign to `location.href` to perform the "redirect".

Comment: Thanks but, I tried to remove the self.redirect("/") and turn it into location.href like this: 
`
if _auth_flag: 
 self.write("<script>alert('Login Successfully');</script> ")
 self.write("<script>location.href='/';</script>")
`

The second js(the redirection) worked correctly, but the alert still did not work.